# ReferenceError: data is not defined while i am using jquery with mvc

Tags: jquery

["ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at eval (eval at success (https://10.5.22.194:8085/QueryBuilder/Index?userId=123Xy7mNS:144:22), :1:1)
    at Object.success (https://10.5.22.194:8085/QueryBuilder/Index?userId=123Xy7mNS:2217:22)
    at i (https://10.5.22.194:8085/Scripts/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27151)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://10.5.22.194:8085/Scripts/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27914)
    at z (https://10.5.22.194:8085/Scripts/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:12120)
    at XMLHttpRequest. (https://10.5.22.194:8085/Scripts/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:15680)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKAqM.png)

Comment: Cannot even begin to think how to help without the actual code, the actual issue, what you are trying to do and when do you get an error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please read the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: If we click on the link it will display the image in the ajax call scdtype and time and date is showing Reference data not found.